# Asp.Net Mvc Account Controller JSon and View?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I m beginner asp.net mvc developer.And I don't understand,
Why has used both Json and ActionResult in Account controller(for register, login and etc.) in default asp.net  MVC 4 project?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the ASP.NET 4 default project?  Earlier versions did not use Ajax.  Your question is not particularly clear.  Do you mean how does it work?  Or why are they using Ajax?  Or do you have a more specific question?

Comment: No, but it's commonly used with Ajax.

Comment: What is the popuse of use in MVC 4. Ajax too?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your english is so bad I just don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: you said json commonly used with ajax. so, in mvc application, it is used for ajax.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: never mind. I cant explain.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the ASP.NET MVC 4 the Login and Register forms are shown in a jQuery dialog and both forms POST to the Account controller using AJAX. The other actions that return views are similar to what existed in previous versions. For example if the user has javascript disabled he won't be able to use jQuery dialog and AJAX and he will fallback to standard HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Do you means having both JsonResult and ActionResult for (register and login view) in default MVC 4 template?

It means two views for both Register & Login form. One is using with ajax and the other is as normal view.

```
eg: Click on "Register" link on top, it will popup ajax "Register" view. 
    Click on "Login" link on top -> click "Register", it will show as normal view.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alariza,

As Darin pointed out, there are two action methods for each form (Register & Login). One action method is used for the popup version of the view and the other is for the normal view.

Don't get discouraged by the negative comments.

Comment: tested it with debugging. when I posted register popup form, worked the json based function. When I post normal view register form, worked the actionresult based function.